# Recursive function including Bessel functions

Tags: special-functions

I was wondering if anybody knows how to solve (numerically) the following recursive equation (found in http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/3.250392):
$$E^{o}_{k}=\sum^{\infty}_{q=-\infty}J_{q-k}(2m)E^{o}_q,$$
with $J$ being the Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on the Mathematics site? This site is for the users of the software *Mathematica*.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: It hard to know what you mean by solve when you only show a definition but no equation. Do you mean 'evaluate'?

Comment: How do you know if the equation has a nonzero solution for a given $m$? Do you know whether the linear system is singular?

Answer (score 0):

@ m_goldberg:
Yes, I'd like to evaluate the above stated definition for a given $m$. One hint was to try it with inverse Fourier transformation but I have no clue how to do that either.